# 'Range' of object'_Global' fail in Do Until

Tags: excel, vba, range

Basically I just found this little code on the web, I thought it might help me because I want to improve it. But on the

```
Do Until Range("A" & amp, R) = ""
```

line I got the mentioned error in the title.

Here is the code:

```
Sub Use_Instr()
    R = 1
    'loop to the last row
    Do Until Range("A" & amp, R) = ""
        'check each cell if contains 'apple' then..
        '..place 'Contains Apple' on column B
        If Range("A" & amp, R) Like "*apple*" Then
            Range("B" & amp, R) = "Contains Apple"
        End If
        R = R + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

It does search the "apple" term in the sentences in A column and write "contains apple" in the B
column if it contains "apple"

Comment: `Range("A" & amp, R)` is not the right way to address the range.  I think I know what happened.. When you copied from the website, it copied the html code as well. Replace `& amp,` with `&`

Comment: In Html `&` is encoded as `&amp;`

Comment: yeah it seems like thank you guys , as you can see im not an expert in vba...

Comment: No probem. BTW you can achieve what you want without using a loop ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
R = 1
'loop to the last row
Do Until Range("A" & R).Value = ""
'check each cell if contains 'apple' then..
'..place 'Contains Apple' on column B
If Range("A" & R).Value Like "*apple*" Then
    Range("B" & R).Value = "Contains Apple"
End If
R = R + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

`Range("A" & amp, R)` is not the right way to address the range. When you copied from the website, it copied the html encoding as well. In Html `&` is encoded as `&amp;`. Simply replace `& amp,` with `&` in your code. So your code becomes

```
R = 1
'loop to the last row
Do Until Range("A" & R) = ""
    'check each cell if contains 'apple' then..
    '..place 'Contains Apple' on column B
    If Range("A" & R) Like "*apple*" Then
        Range("B" & R) = "Contains Apple"
    End If
    R = R + 1
Loop
```

Also to make the code case insensitive, as suggested by @VBasic2008 in comments below, you may want to change `Range("A" & R) Like "*apple*"` to `If LCase(Range("A" & R).Value2) Like "*apple*" Then`.

Having said that, I would use a different approach than using a loop which is a slightly slower approach.

> It does search the "apple" term in the sentences in A column and write "contains apple" in the B column if it contains "apple"

If you were to do this in Excel, then you would use the formula `=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"Contains Apple","")`

[image]

So what we will do is find the last row in Column `B` and then add this formula in the entire range in **one go**! Finally we will convert the formula to values.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim sFormula As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    '~~> This is your formula
    '   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("apple",A1)),"Contains Apple","")
    sFormula = "=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(""apple"",A1)),""Contains Apple"","""")"
    
    With ws
        '~~> Find the last row in column B
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        '~~> Insert the formula in the entire range in 1 go
        With .Range("B1:B" & lRow)
            .Formula = sFormula
            '~~> Convert formula to value
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: For the answer to be consistent, with a short explanation, you should use `If LCase(Range("A" & R)) Like "*apple*" Then` in OP's modified code (since you're using `SEARCH` (not `FIND`) in your improved solution).

Comment: **1.** I am not using a loop **2.** Search is not case sensitive i.e it is case-insensitive :) @VBasic2008

Comment: **1.** You're using a loop in OP's 'repaired' code snippet, right after `... So your code becomes...` and before `Having said that,...`. **2.** The 'repaired' code snippet is case-sensitive.

Comment: @VBasic2008: Ah you mean the original code :D. There I only suggested the change from `& amp` to `&`. Did not try to improve it. Good suggestion. Post updated!